# How to configure xdebug in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, drupal-8

I read several tutorials in the internet but without success. I configured xdebug in my php.ini file like this:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20131226/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
```

[image]

I have following PhpStorm settings:

[image]

I put following breakpoint but it won't work if I reload page

[image]

Comment: It's always a good idea to specify what "several tutorials" you have tried to see 1) what they are telling to do 2) maybe provide another one. Right now I may only say: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm 2) You may be just missing one of the steps in those tutorials that you have read -- your images do not reflect all the steps you did to start debugging.

Comment: Yes I used exactly same tutorial that you specify

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a listener to PhpStorm

[image]
[image]
[image]

And then you will have a debug tab on the bottom

[image]
[image]

Comment: what listener? where do I need to configure it?

Comment: see the screenshots, on your main toolbar there is a dropdown menu

Comment: yes I have edit configurations option, but do I need to do next?

Comment: see the first screenshot, i circled the arrow, let me add an extra few screenshots show exactly what to click

Comment: I tried ut my site isn't remotely situated, it is local website

Comment: that doesnt matter .. remote host just means it connects over tcp/ip rather then over a unix socket. If you connect 127.0.0.1:9000 then that is a remote connection to your local machine